# Django-notifications won't sync

Tags: django, django-south

I'm trying to set up django-notifications in my app.  I'm following the instructions to install it, which are pretty straight-forward:  https://github.com/brantyoung/django-notifications#installation

When I run `manage.py migrate notifications` I get:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table '{{database}}.notifications_notification' doesn't exist")`

I'm at a loss.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 220, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 230, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 305, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 134, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration, database)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 115, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration, database)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 85, in run_migration
    migration_function()
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 61, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notifications/migrations/0002_auto__add_field_notification_data.py", line 14, in forwards
    keep_default=False)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 47, in _cache_clear
    return func(self, table, *args, **opts)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 418, in add_column
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 282, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Users/nicholsp/.virtualenvs/ownership/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'ownershipdb.notifications_notification' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace, to see where the error happens in the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to run `syncdb` before migrating data. The table doesn't exists because it's syncdb that created it, not the migration.

Reference: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

> (If this fails complaining that south_migrationhistory does not exist, you forgot to run syncdb after you installed South.)

Comment: Erg, that I did.  I could have sworn I had.  

For anyone else, I fixed this with `manage.py migrate notifications zero --fake; manage.py migrate notifications`